# pg_dump out of memory problem

Tags: postgresql, outofmemoryerror

Добрый день!

Недавно переехали на **PostgreSQL** на **Linux**

Полная версия:

```
PostgreSQL 9.2.18 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150 623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit
```

И столкнулись с такой проблемой - при выполнении бекапа `pg_dump` съедает всю память и отваливается с ошибкой `out of memory`

Происходит это на шаге:

```
pg_dump: saving database definition
Killed
```

Пробовали все варианты выгрузки.

Особенности БД - очень много `blob`.

Характеристики сервера - 16Gb памяти. Размер БД ~280Gb

На старой машине под **Windows** бекап все-таки выполнялся, но за полтора дня.
Посоветуйте с какими вообще настройками можно поиграться чтобы `pg_dump` отработал?

Comment: С какими параметрами запускаете pg_dump?

Comment: @Мелкий пробовали все варианты, с компрессией и без, пользовательский и текстовый.Стандартный запуск был такой -   pg_dump -Fc -b -v

Comment: Попробуйте ыыгружать в формат каталога.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант - дампить таблицы с блобами отдельно.
Т.е. запускаем

```
pg_dump -h $DUMP_HOST -p $DUMP_PORT -d $DUMP_DB -U $DUMP_USER \
--exclude-table-data="schema_name.table_name" \
-f $DUMPFILE
```

и получаем файл дампа без больших BLOB'ов.

А затем

```
psql -h $DUMP_HOST -p $DUMP_PORT -d $DUMP_DB -U $DUMP_USER -c "\COPY (SELECT * 
FROM schema_name.table_name) TO '$DUMPDIR/$table_name.dmp' binary;"
```

выгрузив таблицу(ы) отдельно